# Prevent confirm form resubmission with flask

Tags: flask, post

I have a flask app with a form. When the user submits the form, the data is saved and a different message is shown in place of the form. When the user refreshes the page, I get the confirm form resubmission message. I know that I need to use a redirect to avoid this, but I want the site to be one page, so I don't want to redirect to another. If I redirect to `"/"`, then it works, but (as expected) the "thank you" message is not shown. Is it possible to keep the site as a single page, avoid the form resubmission message but still show the thank you message? 
**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import forms

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = ""
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///test.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Booking(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    last = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)
    telno = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    message = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)

@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def main():
    filled = False
    form = forms.BookingForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        copy = dict(form.data)
        del copy["submit"]
        del copy["csrf_token"]
        filled = True
        db.session.add(Booking(**copy))
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template("formtest.html", form = form, filled = filled)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from wtforms import validators
from wtforms.fields.html5 import TelField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class BookingForm(FlaskForm):
    first = StringField("First name", validators = [DataRequired()])
    last = StringField("Last name", validators= [DataRequired()])
    telno = TelField("Phone number", validators=[DataRequired()])
    message = TextField("Please provide details of your appointment:", validators = [DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

**formtest.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
<title>Booking form</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
{% if not filled %}
<form action = "/" method = "POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.first.label }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.last.label }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.first() }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.last() }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.telno.label }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.telno() }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.message() }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.submit() }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
{% else %}
<p>Thank you for your interest</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to pass the filled parameter in the redirect call like this:

```
@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def main():
    form = forms.BookingForm()
    filled = request.args.get('filled')
    if filled is None:
        filled = False
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        copy = dict(form.data)
        del copy["submit"]
        del copy["csrf_token"]
        filled = True
        db.session.add(Booking(**copy))
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('main',filled=filled))
    return render_template("formtest.html", form = form, filled = filled)
```

Comment: `TypeError: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filled'` I don't think `redirect` takes parameters.

Comment: Sorry, parameter was for the wrong function. url_for() takes parameters, so it should be `return redirect(url_for('main', filled = filled))`

Comment: This does not seem to work either. The url changes to ?filled=True, so the parameter is being passed in the GET request, but if I print the value of `filled` it is always False.

Comment: I made another change. The problem was that in the first line of main() you would set `filled = False`, so it would treat it as such for the rest of the code regardless of what was passed in. When passing the GET parameter, we need to read it and see what it is, then based on its value go through the rest of the code. This solution should work now.

Answer (score 3):

Add below script in your html file.

```
    <script>
    if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
    }
</script>
```